# C++ constructor order while virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal(const char * color, int childs, float avgLifetime) {
        //Do something
    }
};

class Birds: virtual public Animal {
public:
    Birds(const char * color, int childs, float avgLifetime, float incubation)
    : Animal(color, childs, avgLifetime) {
        //Do something
    }
};

class Flamingo: public Birds {
public:
    Flamingo(const char * color, int childs, float avgLifetime, float incubation, float avgHeight)
    : Animal(color, childs, avgLifetime),
      Birds(color, childs, avgLifetime, incubation) {
        //Do something
    }
};
```

When I try to create new `Flamingo` I skipped the `Animal` constructor.
I guess it's because the `Birds` that heir virtual `Animal`.

I thought it will arrive in order:

```
Animal->Birds->Flamingo
```

Why is it skip the Animal constructor?

Comment: Yes, that is because of the virtual inheritance. The question off-topic: why do you need the virtual inheritance here? The main purpose of the virtual inheritance is to solve the "diamond problem", do you expect this type of issue in animal taxonomy?

Comment: Yes. There are more classes and I have the diamond problem. And that fixed it. But than I encountered that issue...

Comment: Most of the times you face the diamond problem that is a sign of a bad design. You may consider to use composition instead of inheritance. In your case that is not natural to have an animal that is a cat and a dog at the same time.

Comment: Using classes to represent sets of objects is prob a bad idea. Use abstract classes for sets of functions applicable to objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Birds` uses virtual inheritance with `Animal`, then any derivation of `Birds` is also using virtual inheritance with `Animal`. In particular:

```
class Flamingo : public Birds { /* ... */ };
```

is implicitly equivalent to:

```
class Flamingo : virtual Animal, public Birds { /* ... */ };
```

And if you had written it explicitly, then you would have expected to add code to `Flamingo` to call the constructor on `Animal` (or allow `Flamingo` to implicitly invoke `Animal`'s default constructor). Moreover, `Flamingo`'s initialization of the `Animal` instance overrides `Birds`'.

So, the initialization is still `Animal`→`Birds`→`Flamingo`, but the `Animal` initialization is whatever `Flamingo` does, and `Birds`' initialization is skipped, since `Animal` is already initialized.

Answer (score 0):

With virtual base, it is the most derived class which call the virtual base constructor.

So in your case:

```
class Flamingo: public Birds {
public:
    Flamingo(const char* color,
             int childs,
             float avgLifetime,
             float incubation,
             float avgHeight) :
        // Animal(), // it is this one which is called
        Birds(color, childs, avgLifetime, incubation)
    {}
    // ...
};
```

The one from Birds is ignored:

```
class Birds: virtual public Animal {
public:
    Birds(const char* color,
          int childs,
          float avgLifetime,
          float incubation) :
         Animal(color, childs, avgLifetime) // Not called for Flamingo
   {}
   //Do something
};
```

Comment: Can u explain? I'm a beginner with cpp

Comment: Im not sure I understand... what will be the order of the constructor with new Flamingo(params...)? Animal->Birds->Flamingo

Comment: @motis10, the order will be the same i.e Animal->Birds->Flamingo, but `Flamingo` ctor will call the base class `Animal` ctor and not `Birds`. If you do not explicitly call it through `Flamingo : Animal(params)` it will call the default ctor of `Animal`. Try it.

Comment: @SamerTufail great. but how will I explicitly call the Animal(params)?

Comment: @motis10 just do `Flamingo::Flamingo(params): Birds(parms), Animal(parms)`

Comment: @SamerTufail awsome!